# Select checkbox using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

How can I select the checkbox using Selenium with Python?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'Any URL'
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_id("15 Minute Stream Flow Data: USGS (FIFE)").click()
```

I want to select the checkbox corresponding to 15 Minute Stream Flow Data: USGS (FIFE).

I tried as `id`, `name`, `link_text`, but I could not detect it. What should be used?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`find_element`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) with the XPath expression `.//*[contains(text(), 'txt')]` to find a element that contains `txt` as text.

```py
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, 
    ".//*[contains(text(), '15 Minute Stream Flow Data: USGS (FIFE)')]"
).click()
```

**UPDATE**

Some contents are loaded after document load. I modified the code to try 10 times (1 second sleep in between).

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/'
browser.get(url)

for i in range(10):
    try:
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH,
            ".//*[contains(text(), '15 Minute Stream Flow Data: USGS (FIFE)')]"
        ).click()
        break
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('Retry in 1 second')
        time.sleep(1)
else:
    raise e
```

Comment: sorry to tell you that your code is not working in my PC. @falsetru

Comment: whoops! i am using windows 7 64bit python 3.2, selenium 2.39 @falsetru

Comment: @viena, I've just test the same code with Python 3.4.0b2, selenium 2.39, and it just worked.  BTW, what do you mean it is not working? Does the code cause error? No error, but nothing happended?

Comment: @viena, What error do you get? `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException` ?

Comment: yes, with python 3.2 64bit i got raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[contains(text(), \'15 Minute Stream Flow Data: USGS (FIFE)\')]"}' @falstru

Comment: @viena, What you do get if you execute `print(browser.current_url)` (just after `browser.get(url)` statement).

Comment: i obtained http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/#utf8=%E2%9C%93&spatial_map=satellite&spatial_type=rectangle @falsetru

Comment: @viena, You can also use `Waits`. Check out [the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html).

Answer (score 10):

The checkbox HTML is:

```
<input id="C179003030-ORNL_DAAC-box" name="catalog_item_ids[]" type="checkbox" value="C179003030-ORNL_DAAC">
```

so you can use

```
browser.find_element_by_id("C179003030-ORNL_DAAC-box").click()
```

One way you can find elements' attributes is using the Google Chrome Developer Tools:

[image: Inspect element]

Comment: your code also works given that Waits is used as provided by falsetru

Answer (score 10):

You can try in this way as well:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='C179003030-ORNL_DAAC-box']")
```

If you want know if it's already checked or not:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='C179003030-ORNL_DAAC-box']").get_attribute('checked')
```

to click:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='C179003030-ORNL_DAAC-box']").click()
```

Comment: `.get_attribute()` is very useful!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the best approach to click by using Selenium Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'Any URL'
browser.get(url)

box = browser.find_element_by_xpath("paste the XPath expression here")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", box)
```

Comment: I agree, I also use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to select/click the `checkbox` with a complete solution.

this is the [website](https://register.whirlpool.com/en-us/registration) , for example.

and let's say this is the desired `checkbox` on the given website (marked under red loop) to perform a click.
[image]

solution:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://register.whirlpool.com/en-us/registration')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'privacy_policy')))
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('privacy_policy').click();")
time.sleep(2)
var1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "privacy_policy").is_selected()
print(var1)
```

output:

```
True
```

1. First, we wait and locate the element By the available methods(here `By.ID`) to make sure that the target `checkbox` element is loaded/located on the page.
2. Next, execute the javascript query (here `document.getElementById('privacy_policy').click()`) to click on the checkbox.
3. We can also verify if the click or the select was performed on the desired `checkbox` using the method `is_selected()` as mentioned above.
4. It'll return `True` if the checkbox was clicked/selected and `False` otherwise.

You can also cross-check by simply running the javascript query `document.getElementById('privacy_policy').click()` on the Console of the page and you'll see that it indeed performs the click on the desired checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/'
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_name("catalog_item_ids[]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the element "Checkbox" if it has text is to use a JavaScript function to extract it from the webpage:

For example: `//*[text()='text on element']`

Here also you can use the same while extracting the checkbox and use the click() function to check it.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "URl of site"
driver.get(url)
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[text()='text on element'])
checkbox.click()
```

To check whether an element got checked or not, you may use the `get_attribute()` function.

For example: `checkbox.get_attribute('checked')`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading this

https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html?highlight=radio#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.choose

```
browser.check("checkbox_name")
```