# No action to select multiple checkboxes with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**My goal:**

When I access a specific page, I need to click in 10 checkboxes

**My code:**

```
def select_checkbox(self):

    checkboxes = self.find_elements(EventsLocators.CHECKBOX_SELECTOR)

    for each_checkbox in checkboxes:

        each_checkbox.click()
```

**My problem:**

The test result shows success, but no checkbox is selected

**My locator:**

CHECKBOX_SELECTOR = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "Input[type='checkbox']")

**HTML:**

```
<span class="left">
<input id="id_qa-timesheets_facilitator_sign_complete" name="qa-timesheets_facilitator_sign_complete" type="checkbox">
<label>Time sheets complete with team lead sign off</label>
<br>
<span class="help_text"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: so maybe your locator is wrong? show `HTML` along with your exact locator

Comment: @Andersson My question was updated.

Comment: Does `print checkboxes` really returns 10 web-elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select check box using Selenium Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213417/select-check-box-using-selenium-python)

Answer (score 1):

First of all check whether `print checkboxes` really show 10 web-elements. If it so and you still cannot click on check-boxes, try to use `click()` method from `JS` instead of common method (sometimes common `click()` is not working):

```
def select_checkbox():
    checkboxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_locator('input[type="checkbox"]')
    for each_checkbox in checkboxes:
        if not each_checkbox.is_selected(): # just to be sure that you make check, but not uncheck
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', each_checkbox)
```

As I'm not familiar with your framework, I made it as simple function, so change it as you need